# Is there another way to set cookies than through HTTP headers?

Tags: http, cookies, https, http-headers

I'm writing some http client code to interact with a website, and I need to set some cookies. Simply visiting the website sets 4 cookies (as seen in Chrome Settings).

However, when I look at the HTTP response headers for when those cookies were set (using Live HTTP Headers extension), there is no Set-Cookie header anywhere. How were those cookies set? Is there another way than through Set-Cookie?

Edit: Some of the cookies are HttpOnly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load a site in your browser, it might also load other assets that can also set cookies (given that they are on the same domain).

But there is a second way to set cookies: with Javascript via `document.cookies`.

Comment: Yes, I looked at all the HTTP requests (for images and scripts) and none of the responses have Set-Cookie. And what about those cookies that have "Accessible to script: No (HttpOnly)" in the chrome settings?

Comment: httponly cookies can really only be set by HTTP responses.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, and there's no Set-Cookie in any of the HTTP responses.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. Those two are the only 2 ways cookies can be set. That should answer your question. If you can't see it, you're not looking in the right places.

Comment: How come some HttpOnly cookies have been set in my browser without any Set-Cookie headers?

Comment: Either your plugin is not showing all headers, or there were headers that you missed. Maybe take a look with curl on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if your javascript or python code sets a cookie for that domain, then the response will include the SET-COOKIE field. You can view that from at least the inspect console.

So I see that you're using HTTP live extension, but it doesn't look like it shows that field in the response.

I tried looking for other extensions that could show it, but I wasn't able to find one as far as I know. I suppose we both can always fall back to the chrome inspect console. If you go to the network tab, you should actually see the req-resp.

Comment: I'm using Live HTTP headers, tho: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/eaiimeeggnhceafhencnejheejddlcpa

Comment: Yeah, I tried it after you mentioned it in your original post. It doesn't look like it shows those headers.

Comment: Do you know an extension that does show the Set-Cookie headers?

Comment: So I couldn't find one sadly that I know of. My answer should be updated as well as I spoke to my colleague about it. So to be more clear, you should as far as I know always be able to see the SET-COOKIE headers in the response. The HTTP-only business I brought up was actually concerning requests. There is a cookie field in there that should be displayed assuming that HTTP-only field is set to false.